# How to check if void pointer points to arbitrarily low address?

Tags: c, pointers

My program has a set fault because at some point, the value of a pointer is being set to 0x11. I have no idea why or how this is happening, and the code would be too long to post here. So, I'd like to check and avoid this one case where the pointer is pointing to 0x11.

Right now, I have `if (ptr != 0)` which is fine because it checks for NULL pointers. But it doesn't check for this random broken pointer. I tried `if (ptr <= 0x11)` and I also tried casting ptr to various types (`long`, `int`, etc) but it never catches it.

Is there a way to catch this pointer so the `if` statement returns false?

Edit: `ptr` is of type `void*`

Comment: Wrong solution. 0x11 is just an example of a bad value, and there is a (virtually) limitless number of bad values (`2 ^ 64 - some very small number`, to be exact). You need to fix your program. Try memory sanitizer or valgrind, they often can do very good job.

Comment: The fact your variables are getting some values when they should not is pointing to a bigger problem in your code.

Comment: The symptoms indicate that your code has undefined behavior. The biggest problem with undefined behavior is that even the smallest change to the code has the potential to completely change the behavior. So you either need a tool like valgrind, or turn the warnings all the way up, and fix ***all*** of the warnings.

Comment: As @user3386109 says, you should fix the warnings. However, casting is VERY rarely the right way to deal with warnings.

Comment: There are possible two causes: 1. Your code reads uninitialized memory; 2. your code causes data corruption.   You can use https:https://segfault.stensal.com to do segfault self-diagnosis. It can catch both causes.

Answer (score 2):

As SergeyA wrote in the comments, your approach is wrong. You should not look for the particular value `0x11`. It is much more likely that the pointer just happens to have that value.

What I suggest that you do is to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and pay attention to all warnings. I would especially look for uninitialized variables. Remember that pointers are not automatically initialized to null. If uninitialized, they will (probably) have whatever value that just happens to be in memory from before. I say *"probably"* because the compiler *can* initialize them to null, or even another value, without violating the C standard.

Also, as Eugene wrote in a comment, detecting that a pointer has this particular value does not solve your problem. If you're lucky, it may help you finding the problem, but it is most likely a waste of time.

I might mention that your tests are correct. Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void *ptr = (void*)0x11;
    if(ptr == (void*)0x11) printf("ptr == 0x11\n");
    if(ptr <= (void*)0x11) printf("ptr <= 0x11\n");
    if(ptr <= (void*)0x10) printf("ptr <= 0x10\n");
}
```

It outputs:

```
$ ./a.out 
ptr == 0x11
ptr <= 0x11
```

Just as expected. This indicates that your code has *undefined behavior*.

Another thing that you could do is to do an explicit initialization to some value you pick on your own. Look at this code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    // 42 is 2a in hex, and 42 is a good random value
    char *ptr=(void*)0x2a; 


    // If any arguments are supplied to the program         if(argc > 1) {
        ptr = argv[1];
        printf("The first argument has address %p\n", (void*) ptr);
    }

    if(ptr == (void*) 0x2a)
        printf("Something fishy happened.\n");
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Something fishy happened.

$ ./a.out foo
The first argument has address 0x7ffca6323ad8
```

While it is possible that the address of the first argument actually is `0x2a`, it is highly unlikely. I think this might be a pretty good approach to find what's wrong.

Comment: ...and if you're done fixing all the warnings generated by `-Wall -Wextra`, grab that compiler manual and find all the *other* warnings you could enable in addition to those two basic ones. ;-)